# Persisting NSCountedSet to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to persist an `NSCountedSet` of custom objects to `NSUserDefaults`.

I think the problem is that `-(id)objectForKey:` for `NSUserDefaults` has a special consideration in the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/objectForKey:):

```
Special Considerations
The returned object is immutable, even if the value you originally set was mutable.
```

**Question**

How would I go about persisting an `NSCountedSet` if (as I am currently assuming?) `NSUserDefaults` returns a non-mutable `NSSet` from `-(id)objectForKey:` when I need to retain the internal count metadata that `NSCountedSet` contains?

Comment: `NSCountedSet *myCountedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithSet:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:yourKey];`?

Comment: Will this save the count metadata of the data structure?

Comment: Have a look at the NSUserDefaults documentation: *"A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary."* – I cannot see NS(Counted)Set in that list.

Comment: ^ that's it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write an NSCountedSet to user defaults. Only arrays, dictionaries, strings, numbers, date and data.

You could create a dictionary matching the NSCountedSet, with the set elements as keys and the counts converted to NSNumber as values. And of course when you read the dictionary, convert it to a counted set. Just a few lines of code.

Alternatively, convert to an array with values duplicated depending on their count. If the counted set contains "Hello" with a count of 3, add it to the array three times.